# How do I make a terminal quicklist to open a terminal window with a new profile?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, launcher, quicklists

I've seen [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/39532#39532) and [this one.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34597/how-do-i-make-a-custom-launcher-for-terminal-applications/34598#34598) I think I've done what they say to do, but I'm still having trouble.

I've copied `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications/`. I then edited that file to look like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminal
Comment=Use the command line
TryExec=gnome-terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
X-GNOME-DocPath=gnome-terminal/index.html
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-terminal
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=BugBuddyBugs
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.0.1
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;
StartupNotify=true
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=New;NewDev
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-terminal

[New Shortcut Group]
Name=New Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[NewDev Shortcut Group]
Name=New Development Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=Development
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

I then chowned the file to make me the owner instead of root. I closed all my terminals and removed the terminal icon from the launcher.

Now, if I open Terminal from the dash, I get a new launcher icon which has the new quicklist. But if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, it opens a *different* terminal icon, which *doesn't* have the quicklist.

What's worse is that if I keep the new icon in the launcher and then close all terminals, using the new quicklist opens a new terminal with the correct profile, but with a new icon without the quicklist.

I made a [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVQ690axqDs) of some of the weird behavior.

I also tried editing the `/usr/share/applications/` file directly, but that didn't work at all. I got no new quicklist, and clicking on the launcher icon wouldn't load a terminal at all.

What am I doing wrong in creating quicklists?

Comment: There doesn't appear anything wrong with your .desktop.

Comment: Sorry about 2 comments - don't get how they work here. Anyway - Try removing your current launcher icon, then log out/in. After that browse to ~/.local/share/applications & drag that .desktop you created on to the launcher.  (All my terminal quicklists are controlled by the same icon, as is Crtl+Alt+T

Comment: @doug Just tried this. When I use the quicklist to open a new profile Terminal it opens in a new launcher icon. Ctrl + Alt + T also opens in a new launcher icon.

Comment: Can't dup that here, it sounds like you're getting a new process for each of your variations, this would give you new 'running' icons. Have you checked that?

Comment: @doug I don't think it's spawning a new process, because the old icon never has anything running. All of the terminals get grouped into one icon. I made a [video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVQ690axqDs) showing some of the behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you should try is this -

Open your custom gnome-terminal.desktop in a text editor

Remove this line & it's space entirely, then save. You may want to then do a log out/in & try again

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get home, but that line is there in the default .desktop file. The only lines I changed are `X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=New;NewDev` and the last five lines.

Comment: It's 'okay' for that line to be in the installed .desktop, not so when it's in an alternate location. This will also affect other modded .desktop, nautilus-home is another

Answer (score 0):

Its not a problem with quicklists, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> appears to be hard coded to the `gnome-terminal` command. I confirmed this by creating a gnome-terminal symlink in my ~/bin and binding it to a different executable.

To work around this you can create your own short cut with your custom command in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts, as the system commands cannot be edited save for changing the shortcut keys

This will disable the current Terminal Launcher shortcut, if you use the same command.

Comment: It's more than that though. Once I have my quicklist working, if I use it to open a new profile terminal, it will open in another launcher icon. Strangely, this only happens if there aren't any terminal windows open, otherwise it'll just join the currently open terminal icon.