# gnome-terminal and midnight-commander in different Unity Launcher's groups

Tags: unity, launcher

I have a gnome-terminal icon and midnight-commander icon in launcher. When I press mc icon and then press gnome-terminal icon both applications add to the group of applications of mc icon. How can I make them to appear in different icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `--class` argument to each launcher so that gnome-terminal thinks it's a separate application.

You can do this by just making a custom launcher for one of them (probably mc) and pass it

```
gnome-terminal -e mc --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=mc"
```

that should be enough for Unity to classify it as a different application, see here:

- [How do I make a custom launcher for terminal applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34597/how-do-i-make-a-custom-launcher-for-terminal-applications)

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but there is one moment: adding "--class=mc" was not enough. It had to add some more parameters. The whole command is "gnome-terminal -e mc --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=mc"

Comment: @SergeyVeselov Great, glad you solved it, I added your final solution to my answer!