# Saving SSH shell links in launcher like putty

Tags: server, launcher, ssh, command-line, putty

I mean how can I bookmark a *ssh root@ip* command in the launcher so when I click on the icon and a shell is prompt to me asking credentials for the connection to the server shell?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Access of list of your favorite SSH servers quickly.

[image: ssh quicklist]

1. **Create a new file with gedit, in the [Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal/38220) type:**

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ssh-launcher.desktop
   ```
2. **Copy & Paste** this text into the above file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Remote Servers
   Comment=Login to my servers
   Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable --class=remoteserver -x ssh -t minibox.local 
   Terminal=false
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Icon=utilities-terminal
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=RemoteServers
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Server1;

   [Server1 Shortcut Group]
   Name=SSH into minibox.local
   Exec=gnome-terminal --disable-factory --sm-client-disable  --class=remoteserver -x ssh -t minibox.local
   TargetEnvironment=Unity

   Comment=You can create more of these. Just add to X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts a "Server2", "Server3" etc, then change the domain name (in this case, "minibox.local") to the name of your server. You'll also notice that the default action (When you just click the icon in the launcher) is to SSH into minibox.local - you'll need to change that to your most used server.
   ```
3. **Drag and Drop** onto the launcher by navigating to
   ~/.local/share/applications/ in
   Nautilus.

[Source 1](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~jamesgifford/unity-quicklist-examples/trunk/files), [Source 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34597/how-do-i-make-a-custom-launcher-for-terminal-applications)

<sub>(From an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/35523) by [Jorge Castro](https://askubuntu.com/users/235/jorge-castro), [Nik](https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/955) and [Cas](https://askubuntu.com/users/8570/cas))</sub>

Comment: all works fine but if you want more than one link use server1;server2 (use semicolon)