# How to make an icon to enter terminal commands

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Let me start by saying that I'm very new to Ubuntu in general, so I realize this may be a basic question. I'm using xubuntu 14.04. I recently got a wireless usb working by following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577941/installing-the-driver-for-tp-link-tl-wn727n-on-ubuntu-14-04).

The instructions say that anytime the kernel updates, I must recompile by entering the following into the terminal:

```
cd ~/mt7601/src
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe mt7601Usta
```

I'd like to know if there's anyway to create an icon on my desktop that I can just double click that will have the effect of entering the above commands into the terminal?

Answer (score 13):

#### How to create an icon on your desktop to perform the recompile-job

1. Open gedit, paste the lines below into the file:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Recompile
   Exec=/bin/bash -c "cd ~/mt7601/src&&make clean&&make&&sudo make install&&sudo modprobe mt7601Usta"
   Type=Application
   Terminal=true
   ```
2. Save the file as `recompile.desktop` on your desktop
3. Make the file executable by the command:

   ```
   chmod +x /path/to/recompile.desktop
   ```

   After you made it executable, a generic icon will show up on the file (not necessarily the same as in the image, depending on your icon theme).

   [image]
4. Simply double click on the file to run it. it will open a terminal window and ask for your password to run the `sudo` part of the command:

   [image]

#### Explanation

- Desktop files (with the extension `.desktop`) can be used to perform all kinds of applications or tasks. To make it run shell commands, the format is:

  ```
  Exec=/bin/bash -c "<command>"
  ```

  In this case, in the `Exec=` -line, the commands mentioned in your question are separated by `&&`, which is effectively the same as placing each command on a new line.

  This makes it unnecessary to create a separate script; all is included in one launcher.
- To make a `.desktop` file run from your desktop, you have to make it executable.
  After you made it executable, the name as it appears on your desktop is the name, defined in the line:

  ```
  Name=Recompile
  ```
- The line:

  ```
  Terminal=true
  ```

  makes the command(s) run in a terminal window.
- The example file is a very basic one. If you'd like the file to have another icon than the generic one, add a line (e.g.):

  ```
  Icon=/path/to/icon.png
  ```

  [image]

More on `.desktop` files and their required/optional entries [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

Comment: just in case someone else wonders & lose time like I did you cannot use command alias stored in bash-alias in the Exec field

Answer (score 6):

You can make a script that can do these commands for you. Simply create a text file located on your desktop that contains the following.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/mt7601/src
make clean
make
make install
modprobe mt7601Usta
```

Save it to the desktop as kernelupdate.sh 
You should then open up a terminal and run the followings commands

```
cd ~/Desktop/
chmod +x kernelupdate.sh
```

The script is now executable. You can execute it via the terminal using the following commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo ./kernelupdate.sh
```

Here is the link to a related question that explains how to make it executable via clicking on the icon. [How to execute sh script from a desktop shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299052/how-to-execute-sh-script-from-a-desktop-shortcut)

Comment: When I try to enter "chmod +e kernelupdate.sh", it says chmod: invalid mode: '+e'

Comment: My apologies, it should be +x. I'll update answer now.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend running `make` as root.

Answer (score 4):

Low reputation disallows commenting, so the answer instead of comment to Brian's answer.

The script in discussion must be run with root privileges. To avoid some confusion, the shortcut for it's launch should look like

```
gksudo script_name
```

The `gksudo`/`gksu` command brings up graphical dialogue for entering password

Also, the better place to store executables is not desktop, but your home folder. You may

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

And then use this `bin` directory to store this script. It is not strictly required, but strictly recommended to store programs and data in different places, not in one.

Comment: For one, who proposed to replace `gksudo` with `sudo -i`: gksudo does not do the same. GKsudo does not launch login shell