# Running Teamspeak 3 on Ubuntu 14.04 issue

Tags: scripts, teamspeak

I tried installing Teamspeak 3 and got up to the point where I run `ts3client_runscript.sh` and changed it to run as a program. However, it still opens with Gedit.

Can someone help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Teamspeak 3 client on ubuntu 12.04 lts 32 bit?](/q/344616/175814)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to run a .sh file.

1. Ensure the sh file has execution permissions, to do this right click the file and go to properties and ensure <kbd>Allow executing file as program</kbd> is checked.

   [image: Allow executing file as program]
2. Right-click on a blank space *in the folder* that the .sh file is located (**not on the sh file itself!**). Select the option to <kbd>Open in Terminal</kbd> :

   [image: Open in Terminal]
   (You can also just cd into the location of the file like so: 
   `cd ~/Desktop` )
3. Type the following command:

   ```
    ./sample.sh
   ```

   Where `sample` is the name of your file. Be sure to add the `./` at the beginning.
4. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your `.sh` file should run!

Comment: There is no option to open in terminal. Is there another way to do that.

Comment: Yup.. where is your file located

Comment: You can open terminal, browse to the directory, and just run the script with `./ts3client_runscript.sh`.

Comment: @Morpheus you can right click the file, click properties, and the path should be there it may look something like : /home/trevor/Desktop 
copy this, now in the terminal (open it with ctrl+alt+t) type in :
cd /home/trevor/Desktop (or whatever the path was) .. now you can run the ./sample.sh command again

Comment: Its on my desktop

Comment: ok then just do    cd ~/Desktop  then do ./ts3client_runscript.sh or whatever the name of the file is

Comment: hey if this answer helped please press the checkmark to say that this worked and you approve of my answer

Comment: It seems like i have to run those commands everytime to open teamspeak?

Comment: Yes, unless you create a .desktop file, which is a shortcut that can run the .sh file you can follow method here: http://askubuntu.com/a/299073/373012 but replace the information with your information

Comment: @Morpheus: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the following command 
1. First make it executable

```
chmod u+x TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_XXX_XXX.run
```

2. Run the Installer

```
./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_XXX-XXX.run
```

2.1 Press Enter to see the licens
2.2 Press down to scroll down to the end of the licens
2.3 Press Q to exit the licens
2.4 Answer Do you accept the license? (yes/no)" with "yes"
Teamspeak is now extracted at the main directory, the .run file has been.
3. **Execute** Teamspeak with the **Terminal** with ./ts3client_runscript.sh
4. (Optional) you can make a desktop starter like a desktop shortcut in windows

```
cd path/to/your/desktop
gedit teamspeak3-client.desktop
```

And paste the following data.
You may need to change the paths in this file !

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Teamspeak 3 Client
GenericName=Teamspeak
Comment=Speak with friends
Comment[de]=Spreche mit Freunden
Exec=/path/to/teamspeak/ts3client_runscript.sh
Icon=/path/to/teamspeak/pluginsdk/docs/client_html/images/logo.png
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Categories=Network
StartupWMClass=Teamspeak
StartupNotify=true
```

Id took all info from https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/TeamSpeak_3