# What is the difference between starting a program from an unity icon and the command line?

Tags: command-line, unity, python, icons, clion

I have a weird bug that only happens when I start clion from the icon. Clicking on the icon I get: `ImportError: No module named catkin.environment_cache` in the cmake window. When I start clion from the console like I usually do I don't get this error, I get no error at all. I assume it has something to do with the environment variables that are different depending on the way I start it.
I checked jetbrains-clion.desktop and it launches the same binary with the same options I do when starting it from the command line.

**Is there a way to set the same environment variables for a .desktop file, as if the command was run from a terminal?**

Comment: See second answer with 29 votes regarding `terminal=true` https://askubuntu.com/questions/299052/how-to-execute-sh-script-from-a-desktop-shortcut

Comment: Maybe you should add `Path=` directive within the .desktop file. Please provide the content od this file.

Comment: You can start via a terminal window: For the `Exec` line of the desktop file you can use something like `Exec=xterm ... -e program-name %f` where `...` are various options and `program-name` is the name of the program you want to start. Maybe you have to install `xterm` or use another terminal program.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @WinEunuuchs2Unix it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try modifying the CLion `.desktop` entry to open clion with bash by changing the `Exec` line

```
Exec=bash -i -c "/INSTALL_LOCATION/clion-2018.2.3/bin/clion.sh" %f
```

Replace the install location with wherever clion is installed to

Comment: Thank you very much, simply fix that worked for me.